# Semigroup property between pseudodifferential operators and differential operators

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, functional-inequalities, pseudo-differential-operators

Given a positive integer $n$ and a>0.  Let consider the operators $\nabla^n (\cdot)= \sum_{i=1}^d \partial_i^{n}(\cdot) $, and $(1- \Delta)^{\frac a 2} $ defined at the Fourier level as (modulus some numerical constant)
$$
\widehat{(1- \Delta)^{\frac a 2} } (\xi) = (1- |\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}. 
$$

I am wondering if the following inequality holds:

$$
\langle \ 
\nabla^n (1- \Delta)^{\frac a 2} f
,
\nabla^n (1- \Delta)^{\frac a 2} g
\ \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}
\leq 
C
\langle \
 (1- \Delta)^{\frac {a+n} 2} f
,
 (1- \Delta)^{\frac {a+n} 2} g \
\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}.
$$

For me it follows from considering Plancherel Theorem and
$$
|\xi|^n = |\xi|^{2 \frac n 2} \leq  (1+ |\xi|^2)^{\frac n 2},  
$$

but I'm not sure of it. **Do you have any comment or idea?**

In fact my strategy is the following:

By Plancherel we have
$$
\langle \ 
\nabla^n (1- \Delta)^{\frac a 2} f
,
\nabla^n (1- \Delta)^{\frac a 2} g \
\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}
=
 \langle \ 
(i)^n  |\xi|^n (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}  \widehat{f}
,
(i)^n  |\xi|^n (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}  \widehat{g}\
\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}
$$

and considering $|\xi|^n \leq  (1+ |\xi|^2)^{\frac n 2},$

$$
\langle \ 
(i)^n  |\xi|^n (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}  \widehat{f}
,
(i)^n  |\xi|^n (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}  \widehat{g}\
\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}
\leq
\langle \ 
(i)^n  (1+|\xi|^2)^n (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}  \widehat{f}
,
(i)^n  (1+|\xi|^2)^n (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac a 2}  \widehat{g}\
\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}.
$$

Comment: Pardon me for asking my question if it is impertinent. Is $\xi$ defined such that the Laplacian transforms as $|\xi|^2$ instead of $4 \pi^2 |\xi|^2$? Likewise, is $C$ a yet undetermined constant indicating that you care most about the asymptotic behavior of each side of the inequality?

Comment: @Talmsmen yes, exactly, I am looking info about estimates more than the precise $C$ doing the work. Thanks for the comment !

Comment: It is almost right, except that you strange $\nabla$ operator is not the one with symbol $|\xi|^n$, but the one with symbol $\sum_j \xi_j^n$. I write strange because the $\nabla^n$ denotes for me the iteration $n$ times of the operator $\nabla$ which is a vector of derivatives ... and then, this operator $\nabla$ verifies $|\nabla|^n = (-\Delta)^{n/2}$, which has the symbol $|\xi|^n$. At the end they are comparable up to a constant so you still get the result. Of course you also have to remove the $i^n$ when taking inequalities  ...